# intuition behind finding different laurent series for multiple annuli

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

suppose that $f(z) = \frac{1}{z(z^2-1)}$. Singularity exist at $0, +1, -1$. There are three largest annuli centering at 1 $\{0<|z-1|<1\}, \{1<|z-1|<2\}, \{2<|z-1|<\infty\}$.

How do you find the laurent series?

What is the intuition that differentiates the formulation of one laurent expansion from the other?

How are these three laurent series different?

Comment: For rational functions, the typical method is to decompose into partial fractions and find a Taylor series for each term. The Taylor series will be different depending on whether you want one that converges inside or outside a disk, because the Taylor series for outside of a disk is centered at $\infty$

Comment: https://youtu.be/RC15R-ktnUI this video here cleared up some of my questions